# Which instance types could be upgraded to? Determine while instance is running in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, types, amazon-ec2, upgrade, downgrade

In Amazon Web Services (or AWS) EC2; compute instances can be upgraded/downgraded when stopped. However, I'd like to know which instance types are available even when the instance is running, even if I have to stop it to do the upgrade/downgrade. So, is there an API or console interface that will tell me what instance types are available upgrade/downgrade for an instance while its running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You cannot upgrade **ANY** instance while it is running. When upgrade your instance, it is most likely run in a different hardware. So without stopping the instance it is impossible to move our instance to a different physical machine. There is no such thing like `vMotion` in AWS.

I see update to the question. There is no matrix for instance upgrade. There are many factors that affect this:

- Virtualization (PV or HVM)
- Network (EC2 classic or EC2 VPC)
- Platform (32bit or 64 bit)

Take a look at: [Resizing Your Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html)

Comment: Apologies, I updated the title to better reflect the question, I'd like to know what types could be upgraded to if I stopped the instance. But, know that before stopping.